# Eclipse not releasing memory in Java process on Linux

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, memory

My Linux server need to be able to handle 30+ eclipse instances for developers. I did a quick test of running 10 eclipse instances. The Java process associated with each eclipse initially around 200MB RSS memory, increased up to around 550MB, when more projects are loaded.

But Java process doesn't seem to release memory, after closing/deleting all projects within eclipse instances. I still see it uses over 550MB RSS.

How can I change Eclipse or Java settings so that memory foot print got reduced when developers closed down projects or being idle for a while?

Thanks

Comment: 30+ instances of Eclipse running on the same machine seems too many. How much memory do you have? I'd allocate at least 512MB for each instance, increasing towards 1GB for comfortable use. (Of course, this may depend on the type of development you're doing and the number of plugins you require.)  As Bill K said in his answer, you can configure the `-Xmx` parameter in `eclipse.ini`.

Comment: If you have 30 developers using the same server, how much memory do you have?  You will find that development requires alot of files to be cached to perform well (this can be more than the size of the application) and I would sugegst you have at least 1 GB of cache per developer if not more depending on the size of your project.

Comment: @Bruno beat me to the same comment, spooky.

Comment: I make this comment because I moved from sharing a machine with 24 GB to one with 48 GB and saw a significant improvement. (And a much smaller number of developers than the OP has)

Comment: If you run multiple JVMs on the same machine make sure you benefit from Class Data Sharing introduced in Java 1.5, this will save memory across JVMs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to experiment with these (and other) [JVM tuning options](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html) to make the JVM less reluctant to return memory to the OS:

**-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio**    Maximum percentage of heap free after GC to avoid shrinking. Default is 70.
**-XX:MinHeapFreeRatio**    Minimum percentage of heap free after GC to avoid expansion. Default is 40.

However, I suspect that you won't see the eclipse process shrink to anywhere near its initial size, since eclipse is a huge, complex application that probably lazy-loads (but does not unload, once used) a lot of classes and associated data structures.

Comment: Wow, cool.  Never saw that.  On the other hand, I've STILL never seen Java release memory, so I'd guess that, like you said, it probably won't help much.  Will adjust my answer according.

Answer (score 2):

I've never seen Java release memory.

I don't think you will get any value out of trying to get it to release memory with Eclipse, I've watched that little memory counter for YEARS and never once see the allocated memory drop.

You might try one of these.
After each session, exit the JVM and restart.

Set your -Xmx lower.

Separate your instances into categories with high -Xmx and low -Xmx and let the user determine which one he wants.

As a side-thought, if it really mattered to you, you MIGHT be able to run multiple eclipse instances under one VM.  It would probably be WAY too much work (man-weeks to man-years), but if you could get it right you could reduce overhead by like 150-200mb/instance.  The disadvantage would be that a VM crash (Pretty rare these days) would kill everyone.

Testing this theory would be a matter of calling eclipse's main from within an existing JVM and trying to get it to display somewhere useful.  The rest of the man-year is spent trying to figure out where they used evil static variables or singletons and changing them to something else.

Comment: In other words, this question is not specific to Eclipse at all.

Comment: -1: It's definitely not true that Java never releases memory.

Answer (score 1):

Switch the Java to use the G1 garbage collector with the HeapFreeRatio parameters. Use these options in eclipse.ini:

```
-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=5
-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=25
```

Now when Eclipse eats up more than 1 GB of RAM for a complicated operation and switched back to 300 MB after Garbage Collection the memory will be released back to the operating system.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking on garbage collection, setting right options or even forcing GC periodically might increase time till eclipse memory usage grows high.
Following link might be useful http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t93757.html